# Segmentation error but I can't find where

Tags: c, csv

I'm stuck as I don't understand why my parser code is not working one compiler just says segmentation error. While another compiler compiles it but it just returns an error code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *
getfield (char *line, int num)
{
  const char *tok;
  for (tok = strtok (line, ","); tok && *tok; tok = strtok (NULL, ",\n"))
  {
    if (!--num)
      return tok;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int
main ()
{
  FILE *stream = fopen ("input", "r");
  FILE *fp;
  char line[1024];
  while (fgets (line, 1024, stream))
  {
     char *tmp = strdup (line);
     char buf[0x100];
     snprintf (buf, sizeof (buf), "c:\\temp\\%s.txt", getfield (tmp, 1));
     fp = fopen (buf, "w");
     int count = 0;
     while ((tmp = strchr (tmp, ',')) != NULL)
     {
       count++;
       tmp++;
     }
     if (count == 4 ){
       fprintf (fp,
               "{This is my name %s\n I'm %s years old\n my       useragent is %s\n My hobbies are %s\n}",
               getfield (tmp, 1), getfield (tmp, 2),
               getfield (tmp, 4), getfield (tmp, 5));
     }
     else {
        fprintf (fp,
                 "{This is my name %s\n I'm %s years old\n my       useragent is %s%s\n My hobbies are %s\n}",
                 getfield (tmp, 1), getfield (tmp, 2),
                 getfield (tmp, 4), getfield (tmp, 5),
                 getfield (tmp, 6));
     }

     fclose (fp);
     free (tmp);
   }
}
```

I have a csv file with thousands of lines. example

```
Name,age,gender,useragent,hobby
maximilian,16,Male,Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko,skateboard
```

Im trying to make a file for each name and add the other information in it. so it would output this for example

```
maximilain.txt

This is my name maximilian
 I'm 16 years old
 my useragent is Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
 My hobbies are skateboard
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `getfield (tmp, 1)` modifies `tmp` and `getfield (tmp, 2)` expects a not modified `tmp`.

Comment: Check if `stream` is `NULL` right after `FILE *stream = fopen("input.TXT", "r");` and abort if yes. Not doing so could result in a segfault if the file cannot be opened for some reason. Same for `fp`. On most modern Windows you cannot write to `C:\temp`.

Comment: Please edit the question so that it has consistent indention and brace placement. Your coding style is all over the place, making this hard to read.

Comment: @El.Ham "segmentation fault program finished with exit code 139"

Comment: @humptydumpy1 because of your while setting _tmp_ null after. Look at my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

after

> ```
> while ((tmp = strchr (tmp, ',')) != NULL)
> {
>   count++;
>   tmp++;
> }
> ```

*tmp* is NULL, so the next call to getfield will get a null pointer, the *while* must be done on an other pointer or you need to save tmp before

for example do :

```
char * p = tmp;

while ((p = strchr (p, ',')) != NULL)
{
  count++;
  p++;
}
```

---

As it was already said in remark your use of *strtok* is wrong because the string is modified after each call.

You can modify *getfield* to work on a copy :

```
const char *
getfield (char *line, int num)
{
  static char l[1024];
  strcpy(l, line);
  const char *tok;
  for (tok = strtok (l, ","); tok && *tok; tok = strtok (NULL, ",\n"))
  {
    if (!--num)
      return tok;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

But this is a poor way to do because each time to have to go throw the string bypassing more and more tokens.

I let you optimize your code to extract each token only one time on each line.

---

Note also that you use the first line of the csv, so you create a file based on 'Name' etc